# P/Invoke breaks with vc140 compiler

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a library compiled with visual c++ 2015 (vc140);
I have a client application in c# targeting .net framework 4.6.1.

The client application cannot call (P/Invoke) any functions exported from the library (getting "dll not found" exception); however, when I changed the compiler to vc120 (visual c++ 2013), everything works correctly.

Is this a setup issue?

Comment: Looks like the DLL is simply in a different location from where your client application is expecting it.

Comment: The dll needs to be in the correct subfolder of bin depending on the compiler options (x86, Debug, Release).When you add to a project an "Existing Item" and select the executable (.exe,.dll, ..)The compiler will automatically copy the executable from the source folder to the correct bin folder.Problems can occur if you manually put the executable into the bin folder (depending on version of c#).  Some versions have a Rebuild All option that will remove all files from bin.The only time I found you need to manually put dll into bin folder is with old dll that aren't designed to work with windows

Comment: I tried to use full path in the P/Invoke definition but still does not help. I have verified the architecture match (x64 in both client and server setup). Again it seems to be related to vc140 compiler because compiled with vc120 it always works.

Comment: Either the dll or a dependency cannot be found. It's not going to be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to a d3d dll used in the C++ AMP library (which is odd). After adding the reference to the dll, the issue is resolved.